# How to call ELF function on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, elf

I've tryed to reverse manually some game functions of ELF file (libGame.so) but they are too long and I get a lot of errors, so I thought if it's posible to call those functions in Windows cause procesor is x86. A function what i've try to revert is:

> CDecryptBaseClass::decrypt(void *ptr, u32 lenght);

I've been looking and I only find how to call DLL functions, maybe there's some hack to run the ELF as DLL...

Comment: ELF is a different file format not supported by Windows family natively. You can't use it just like you do with a DLL...

Comment: Its calling only two functions what they don't have any reference to other's SO functions, so it will might be posibly...

Comment: Not because it isn't a SO's function/part of WINAPI it can work. It's the file format which is different. Windows doesn't know how to deal with it.

Comment: So the only way to trigger it is calling in Linux distros?

Comment: Not only linux but any envrionment which does support ELF file format too.

Comment: You should try to get the sources of this lib, and compile it natively on your windows machine.

Comment: It's possible in theory. Wine's loader does the same kind of thing -  loading Windows PE files on Linux and Mac OS X (where the native executable formats are ELF and Mach-O, respectively). Making a loader to load ELF binaries on Windows would be non-trivial, to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you can do this, as Andrew Medico suggests. Load the binary into memory, parse the ELF file, somehow resolve all its external references, find the address of function you want to call and then jump to it. But there are two problems with this, the first is that it'll be far more work than just reverse engineering the function. The second is that a quick search of the web reveals that you probably took `libgame.so` from an Android game. Most Android devices use ARM CPU so the machine code isn't going to be compatible with the your x86 CPU.

This however suggests one possible solution for your problem. Create a simple Android application that loads `libgame.so` and decrypts things for you. Use the Android emulator Google provides with their development kit to run the application.

Comment: They have the library in ARM and also x86, for that I thought it was posibly to done. I already thought about done an app for android, that night I'll start downloading SDK...

Comment: Note that even if it contains x86 code, if it's an Android library it probably contains Android calls that won't work on windows.  Also, if its x86_64, then it uses a different calling convention as well.

Comment: The function in question is a pure C++ function. There's code floating around for a decompile of that function. But just FYI, before decryption you would need to call decryptSetup which seems all wacky with cross references to stuff.